# How to pass result of shell command in ipython interpreter back to python variable

Tags: shell, ipython

I've not had any luck in figuring out how to do this:

In ipython, if I execute the following command

```
var = 'abc'
!echo $var | rev
```

it works as expected. But, how to capture the output of the shell command back to a variable in python (like `new_var = !echo $"var" | rev`)?

I've tried most of the examples here [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output) with no luck, since the variable `var` isn't working as expected when passed to any of the many solutions using the subprocess library.

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked:

In [99]: out =!echo $var | rev

In [100]: out
Out[100]: ['cba']

(the issue was that my shell command was in a for loop where I was reading a file line by line, I didn't expect line breaks there, which was causing the `|` to screw up the bash command. A simple `strip()` on each line, - which was my `var` - before it was passed to the `echo` fixed that)